# Azure Kubernetes - No connection to Server

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl

when I execute the following PowerShell command:

```
.\kubectl get nodes
```

I get no nodes in response. I noticed that the config file from kubectl is empty too:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: ""
  name: cl-kubernetes
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

When I enter the server address at the config file, I get the message that the connection was refused. I suspect that it is due to missing certificates. During another installation this (apparently) following information was created automatically, which is now missing:

certificate-authority-data,
contexts - cluster,
contexts - user,
current context,
users - name,
client-certificate-data,
client-key-data,
token,

Could that be it? If so, where do I get this information?

Many thanks for the help

Comment: did you run `az aks get-credentials` before running kubeclt?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was exactly the problem

Comment: glad to hear it. I'll make an answer out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Azure CLI first to get the credentials. Run

```
az aks get-credentials
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-get-credentials